# PC Scanning using Mac Mini attached MFC printer

Tags: mac-mini, scanning

A Brother MFC 7420 is attached to an Apple Mac Mini and network shared for printing and scanning.
The Mac Mini will print and scan fine.

A Laptop PC running Vista is attached to the same network, and using Bonjour for Windows will print to the same printer.

Using the laptop to try and scan with Windows Fax/Scan returns "No scanner found"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the Brother driver suite on the vista machine?  The Brother "Scan to..." feature is an option in the software installation.  When prompted, you can have the installer include your vista machine in the "Scan to..." options on the printer.  My experience is with the 9440 and 9460, but the driver packages are probably similar.

[32-bit Vista Driver package](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/dlf/000000/004600/dlf004654.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc7420_all&type2=1&os=74&flang=8&dlid=dlf004654)

[64-bit Vista Driver package](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/dlf/000000/004600/dlf004654.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc7420_all&type2=1&os=84&flang=8&dlid=dlf004654)